# An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, urllib3, botocore

### I'm facing the issue in two python libraries used in my code, Getting these randomly on prod on some of the pods and not all pods

### Trace of The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py\", 
line 448, in send\n 
urllib_response = conn.urlopen(\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py\",
line 703, in urlopen\n
httplib_response = self._make_request(\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/external_urllib3.py\",
line 32, in _nr_wrapper_make_request_\n 
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)\n 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py\",
line 386, in _make_request\n    self._validate_conn(conn)\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py\", 
line 1040, in _validate_conn\n    
conn.connect()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py\", 
line 416, in connect\n    
self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py\",
line 424, in ssl_wrap_socket\n    context.set_alpn_protocols(ALPN_PROTOCOLS)\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py\", 
line 566, in set_alpn_protocols\n    
if len(b) == 0 or len(b) > 255:\nTypeError: 'int' object is not callable\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  
File \"/code/app/aws_utils/dynamo_db.py\", line 176, in update_multi_attributes\n 
response = table.update_item(\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py\",
line 580, in do_action\n 
response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)\n 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py\",
line 88, in __call__\n    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)\n 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py\",
line 514, in _api_call\n 
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", 
line 921, in _make_api_call\n 
http, parsed_response = self._make_request(\n 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", 
line 944, in _make_request\n 
return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)\n 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/external_botocore.py\", 
line 108, in _nr_endpoint_make_request_\n 
result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)\n 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\",
line 119, in make_request\n 
return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)\n 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\", 
line 231, in _send_request\n 
raise exception\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\", 
line 281, in _do_get_response\n 
http_response = self._send(request)\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\", 
line 377, in _send\n    return self.http_session.send(request)\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py\", 
line 493, in send\n 
raise HTTPClientError(error=e)\nbotocore.exceptions.HTTPClientError: An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: 'int' object is not callable\n",
```

Getting this in all dynamodb calls , adding one of the codes here, exception comes in the packages and not in the code as far as i understood

```
def update_multi_attributes(
        self,
        table,
        partition_key,
        sort_key,
        attr_value_dict,
        delete_attr=[],
    ):
        try:
            if not partition_key or not sort_key:
                return None
            if not attr_value_dict and len(delete_attr) == 0:
                return None
            if not attr_value_dict and len(delete_attr) > 0:
                return self.delete_attributes(
                    table=table,
                    partition_key=partition_key,
                    sort_key=sort_key,
                    delete_attr=delete_attr,
                )
            expression_attribute_values = {}
            expression_attribute_names = {}
            update_expression = "SET "
            remove_attr_expression = "REMOVE "
            index = 0
            attr_value_dict.pop("partition_key", None)
            attr_value_dict.pop("sort_key", None)

            for key, value in attr_value_dict.items():
                index += 1
                var_name = "#var" + str(index)
                var_value_name = ":var" + str(index)
                expression_attribute_values[var_value_name] = value
                expression_attribute_names[var_name] = key
                if index < len(attr_value_dict.keys()):
                    update_expression = (
                        update_expression + var_name + "=" + var_value_name + ","
                    )
                else:
                    update_expression = (
                        update_expression + var_name + "=" + var_value_name
                    )
            index = 0
            for attr in delete_attr:
                index += 1
                var_name = "#rvar" + str(index)
                expression_attribute_names[var_name] = attr
                if index < len(delete_attr):
                    remove_attr_expression = remove_attr_expression + var_name + ","
                else:
                    remove_attr_expression = remove_attr_expression + var_name
            if len(delete_attr) > 0:
                update_expression = update_expression + " " + remove_attr_expression
            response = table.update_item(
                Key=self.get_key(partition_key, sort_key),
                ExpressionAttributeNames=expression_attribute_names,
                UpdateExpression=update_expression,
                ConditionExpression="attribute_exists(partition_key)"
                "and attribute_exists(sort_key)",
                ExpressionAttributeValues=expression_attribute_values,
            )
            return response
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            logger.info(
                "Dynamo: Error Update MultiAttribute boto3{} error{},{}for{},{}".format(
                    attr_value_dict,
                    e,
                    e.response["Error"],
                    partition_key,
                    traceback.format_exc(),
                )
            )
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info(
                "Dynamo: Error Update MultiAttribute {} error {} for {}, {}".format(
                    attr_value_dict, e, partition_key, traceback.format_exc()
                )
            )
        return None
```

### Adding Package versions used

urllib3-1.26.8
botocore-1.27.77
boto3-1.24.77

Had put a trace print, thinking of upgrading the urllib version but not sure if that would solve the problem, Suddenly this error started coming up, code was working fine for a month after integration.`